# Storybook 7.* upgrade with NextJS: how to transpile modules

Tags: next.js, storybook

I am trying to upgrade to storybook latest/7.* and running into issues with transpiling modules. There is little help to be found in storybook docs. All help appreciated.

```
const path = require("path");
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
  "module1",
  "module2"
]);

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.js"],
  addons: ["storybook-addon-next", "@storybook/addon-links", "@storybook/addon-essentials", "@storybook/preset-scss"],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: withTM({})
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work:

```
framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {
      transpilePackages: ["module"]
    }
  }
```